# JIRA Statuses and Assigned users

Tags: jira

I am wondering how you guys handle changes to Assignee and status changes. In other system we have had multiple assignees.

Example: 
I pickup a work item from the sprint back log. Change status to development, and assign to myself.

When I am done I move the ticket to ready for test, then qa picks it up and assigns their self?

Is this how the rest of you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the task is created, it is automatically assigned to the person responsible for checking tasks before approving for development.

Marking it as Unassigned means it is approved for development and it shows up in the sprint backlog.

When a task is picked up from the sprint backlog, it is assigned to the current user and its status changes to development (in progress).

When the task is moved to "ready for testing", it is auto-assigned to the tester or the testing team lead.

Marking it as "testing passed" assigns it to the person responsible for the deploy.

Comment: So the workflow does some work automatically setting an assigned?

Comment: yes, the task is automatically assigned

Comment: As far as I know, this is a process that needs to be setup in the workflows. By default, JIRA does not auto-assign tickets per-status.

Answer (score 1):

### We create tasks under stories

We use Jira Agile (formerly GreenHopper). Much of the work of the team within a sprint happens in "Work" mode.

In the second half of the sprint planning meeting, we create tasks based on how the team plans to implement each story. This you can do by clicking on the "Create Subtasks" button in the issue detail view. Typically, we create several tasks for larger stories. When a team member picks up a task for the next priority story, they will assign it to themselves and drag-and-drop it from the "To Do" column to the "In Progress" column. When they are done, they will drag-and-drop it in the "Review" column. The status of the task will change to "Resolved". The Product Owner can drag-and-drop individual tasks to the "Done" column, if they are separately verifiable, or drag-and-drop the entire story. They will now be in "Closed" status. Once all sub-tasks are closed the parent story will be automatically closed.

These columns in "Work" mode can be customized to suit your workflow.